# Cannot connect from .NET app to SQL Server 2016 using System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a .NET app that I just moved to a new Windows 2016 server with SQL Server 2016, but I cannot connect via the app. The database is on the same server as the app. I have other Classic ASP app that connect to this database without issue.

My .NET connection string in the web.config:

```
<add name="DMLConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=someservername;Initial Catalog=UAT_Corp_CTDML;User ID=someusername;Password=somepassword;Persist Security Info=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

also tried

```
<add name="DMLConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Server=someservername;Database=UAT_Corp_CTDML;User ID=someusername;Password=somepassword;Persist Security Info=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The connection info is good as I can to the database via Management Studio.
I checked the server configuration part and all protocols are enabled.

If I put the old database information (SQL Server 2012 - hosted on different server) back into DB connection string it works fine so I know the app is set up correctly.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: Should be Windows 2016 server...typo

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Knowing the error would be step one. Post the error message. Without it nobody can possibly help.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to post your connection string from `web.config` as well as that error message that @SeanLange mentions. :) Have you also checked the SQL Server logs? Either way, what do they say?

Comment: What is the exception you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Stupid mistake on my part. Error was result of a typo that I starred at for hours and didn't notice. Thanks for the responses.